# Angular JS - add a custom header to all GET/POST requests

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, authorization, request-headers, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to use an interceptor to add an 'Authorization' header to all my GET/POST requests.
Here is the interceptor:

```
myApp.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
  return {
    request: function ($config) {
        $config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.apiKey;
        return $config;
    }
  };
}]);
```

The interceptor is being used in the main module as follows in the myApp.config part:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
```

For some reason I can't see the Authorization header in the network tab(I'm using Chrome) and it's not getting to the server and I don't get any errors.
The GET/POST request in my application are to a remote server that is NOT in my domain.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

**Solution:**
I found the problem, it was on the server side - apparently if I set the Access-Control-Allow-Headers in the response to * it doesn't work but if I specify the headers literally it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was on the server side - apparently setting the Access-Control-Allow-Headers in the response to * didn't work but specifying the headers literally to what i needed(Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization) works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change it to

```
 myApp.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var injector = {
        request: function (config) {
               config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.apiKey;
               return config;
        }
    };
   return injector;
    } ]);
```

try like this [website](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)

Comment: @user1531186 have you tried the solution i have edited?

Comment: i found a solution, see the edited question.
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
myApp.run([
  '$http', '$rootScope',
  function($http, $rootScope) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.apiKey;
  }
]);
```

Comment: Strange I am using something like this in my current application and it work. Here is a jsfiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/epnxmkwy/

I can see in the chrome tools that is sends the header: Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization

Comment: When do you set the $rootScope.apiKey?

Comment: i found a solution, see the edited question.
thanks for the help.

Comment: Good to know that you found the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can always tell angular to add the header using the `$httpProvider` like this:

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider','$rootScope', function ($httpProvider, $rootScope) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic' + $rootScope.apiKey;
}]);
```

This will add the header to ALL requests. For get and post, you can set the :
    `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Authorization'] = '';` and
    `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Authorization'] = '';`
instead of `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']`  if you don't want the header to be added to all requests.

Comment: tried this as well, its not working. also made sure i have Access-Control-Allow-Headers header on the response and its set to *.

Comment: @user1531186 Could you try creating a fiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: i found a solution, see the edited question.
thanks for the help.